# kendo dropdownlist showing selected value when page rendering

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

Currently i'm facing one weird problem - when my page is rendering in browser, kendo dropdownlist showing its selected value (selected id). You can see it in below screenshot. But after completion of page load it rendered perfectly fine.

[image]

We have already refereed this link - [Kendo DropDownList Shows DataValueField Prior to DataTextField when Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977167/kendo-dropdownlist-shows-datavaluefield-prior-to-datatextfield-when-loading)
But in this answer, they'll hide dropdown before render. I don't want it.
We have used kendo dll version - 2015.1.408.545

Answer (score 0):

If quicker initialization is not possible, then another option is to use the `kendo.ui.progress` method to display a loading animation and overlay the content of the page, until it is ready to be used.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/ui#methods-progress